# withRowAnimation effect disappears if user scrolls Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, animation

I'm facing a bugging issue concerning the `insertRowsAtIndexPaths` function and precisely it's `withRowAnimation` parameter.

With the help of the stack community i've been able to modify the effect of insertion from fast fade to a longer fade (by overriding the function), but the whole effect completely disappears if i scroll the table view upwards, hide the cells from the view and scroll back again.

Because the cells are being reused the effect is rendered totally useless.
I've tried using `scrollToRowAtIndexPath` function (doesn't work in this case - it initiates after the cells have already loaded, only then it scrolls down and the effect has already gone away) as well as setting the content offset to `tableView.contentSize.height` - the result is somewhat satisfactory, but again doesn't prevent vanishing of the insertion effect when the user scrolls.
Also `willDisplayCell` is not an option, because it animates the cell every single time the user scrolls and i need the animation to run just once. Urrgh)

So far i'm out of ideas of how to prevent this issue from happening.

**UPDATE:**
Added the suclass code

```
class CustomTable: UITableView{

override func insertRowsAtIndexPaths(indexPaths: [NSIndexPath], withRowAnimation animation: UITableViewRowAnimation) {

    self.endUpdates()
    self.beginUpdates()

    for indexPath:AnyObject in indexPaths{

        let cell:UITableViewCell? = (super.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath as! NSIndexPath));
        if cell != nil {

            cell!.alpha = 0

            let animationBlock = { () -> Void in

                cell!.alpha = 1;
            }
            if UIView.respondsToSelector(Selector("animateWithDuration(duration: , delay: , usingSpringWithDamping dampingRatio: , initialSpringVelocity velocity: , options: , animations: , completion: ")){
                UIView.animateWithDuration(3, delay: 3.0, usingSpringWithDamping: 1.5, initialSpringVelocity: 0.0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.TransitionCrossDissolve, animations: animationBlock, completion: nil)
            }else{
                UIView.animateWithDuration(3.3, delay: 5.0, options:UIViewAnimationOptions.TransitionCrossDissolve, animations: animationBlock, completion: nil)
            }

        }     

    }

}
```

}

Comment: Do you mean that the custom fade effect doesn't work if you insert a 're-used' cell?  Can you show some code?  It sounds like you are setting some variable in your cell subclass that you need to clear in `prepareForReuse`

Comment: @Paulw11 the custom fade effect works only when the cells are visible on the screen, once i scroll in any direction to hide those cells and scroll back to show them again - they ignore the animation and just appear like they do with `reloadTable` approach.

Comment: @Paulw11 i've added the code for my subclass of the `UITableView`

Comment: I still don't understand what you want to happen when a scroll to a previously inserted cell appears?  You want that cell to fade in rather than just appear ?or are you saying that if you insert a cell after a cell that is offscreen then you want that cell to fade in the first time that it scrolls into view?

Comment: @Paulw11 i just want the cell to fade in with the duration of 3 seconds, despite whether its on screen or off screen. so answering your question - i want it to fade in rather than just appear.

Comment: So, your problem is that if the cell isn't on screen then `cellForRowAtIndexPath` will return nil, and when you scroll then the cell will just appear because the insertion operation has already occurred.  You will need to track the state of your inserted cells in an array or similar and perform the fade in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` the first time a cell is displayed

Comment: @Paulw11 that sounds like a solution. But I'm not really sure how to track the state.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88958/discussion-between-paulw11-and-david-robertson).